# How I pass Parameters into Url with Get in Localhost with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, localhost

I want to consume my api. it is in go lang. i use axios in front (react) for consume it

my route:

localhost:1323/profile/email/:email/password/:password

i don't know how i can pass the email and password in axios request with get.

my code:

```
import axios from 'axios'

    export async function validLogin(email, password) { 
      const valid = await axios.get('localhost:1323/profile/email/'+ email + '/password/'+ password).then((response) => {
        return response;
      });
      return valid
    }
```

I tried to use http://localhost instead localhost pure, but don't work too.

Comment: Don't pass passwords through URLs, they are likely to get recorded in log files. Authentication should be done through POST requests (or Authorization headers).

Answer (score 1):

- You need the scheme.
- You need to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) special characters (like `@`!) before shoving them into the URL.
- Template strings save on concatenation

Such:

```
const url = `http://localhost:1323/profile/email/${encodeURIComponent(email)}/password/${encodeURIComponent(password)}`
```